# Launch Chrome app using extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have a standalone frame-less Chrome app. I'm sending messages from another Chrome extension to it (Chrome app) which works. But **I would like to be able** (if it's possible) **to launch the app using the extension.** Because now I have to launch the app manually.

I've seen [Google music "mini player"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-play-music/fahmaaghhglfmonjliepjlchgpgfmobi) that you can launch from [music.google.com](https://play.google.com/music/listen). So I'm wondering if the same can be done using chrome extension.

I wouldn't need the Chrome extension if the Chrome app could read opened tabs or just URLs but  since this is not possible one must use extension and message to app to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just send msg to your app from extension when you want to open it (In my case, I'm opening app when injected element on page is clicked)

**extension script:**

```
var appID = "qwertzuiopasdghghjkhgjghj";

element.onclick = function () {
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage(appID, {message: 'fireup'}, function(response){});
});
```

**app background script:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message == 'fireup') {
    chrome.app.window.create("page.html",
        {
                   //whatever
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chrome.management.launchApp` method: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-launchApp

To use it you need to add "management" permission to your extension manifest file